# How is INTEGER linear programming implemented in the Mathematica LinearProgramming function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, implementation-details

I was surprised to see that, for `d = 1000`, `b = 800`, *Mathematica* solves an integer linear (LP) program such as

```
LinearProgramming[w, A, Table[1.0,{b}], Table[{0,1}, d], Integers]
```

almost as fast as it takes to solve the linear program

```
LinearProgramming[w, A, Table[1.0,{b}] ]
```

for a sparse `b x d` matrix `A`, with entries 0 or 1. The linear program did not have an integral solution. I have been unable to trace in the documentation the method by which integer LP is implemented.

Does anyone know?

Comment: This integer LP problem is Minimum Weight Set Cover, which is NP hard.

Comment: COIN-CLP is used under the hood, IIRC.

Comment: Yes, COIN-CLP is invoked by `LinearProgramming`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the comments, [COIN-CBC](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) is used by [`LinearProgramming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html) for integer problems.